# Automatically classify elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I am building an itinerary of vegetation types for a given location. Data is passed to me as a CSV and I want a way in which I can automatically re-classify items in one column, into broader classes that I provide. I can already read the data in with pandas, do a bit of housekeeping and then write out the data frame to a new file.

However, given I am provided with a column such that:

```
species = ['maple', 'oak', holly, 'sawgrass', 'cat tails'...... 'birch']
```

I would like to be able to automatically, reclassify these into broad categories using another list like:

```
VegClass = ['Tree', 'Bush', 'Grass']
```

The only way I know to do this would be to iterate through the species list, in a manner similar to:

```
out = []
for i in species:
    if species[i]=='Oak':
    out.append('Tree')
```

but this would require that I write a lot of code if the species list becomes very large and I don't imagine it would be very efficient with large datasets.

Is there a more direct way of doing this? I understand that I would need to list all the species manually (in separate classes) e.g.:

```
TreeSpecies = ['oak'....'birch']
GrassSpecies = ['Sawgrass....']
```

but I would only have to do this once to build a dictionary of species names. Im expecting more data so may have to add an additional species name or two in future, but this would not be considered too time intensive if I could process a lot of the data quickly.

Comment: You need a dictionary that specifies{'oak': 'Tree'} etc which you can then use to map your column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a dict of classifier mappings for your different items, for instance,

```
classifier = {'oak': 'Tree', 
              'maple': 'Tree', 
              'holly': 'Tree', 
              'sawgrass': 'Grass',
              'cat tails': 'Bush', 
              'birch': 'Tree'}
```

Then getting a column of groups is as simple as calling [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) on your column.

```
>>> df.species.map(classifier)

0     Tree
1     Tree
2     Tree
3    Grass
4     Bush
5     Tree
Name: species, dtype: object
```

so you can set a new column with

```
df['classification'] = df.species.map(classifier)
```

Comment: Although I understand the idea behind a dict, its something that I've never ventured into using before so wasn't too sure where to start, especially within pandas. This is a really useful example I can work off

Answer (score 1):

You need a dictionary like

```
VegClass = {'oak': 'Tree', 'seagrass': 'Grass'}
df['class'] = df['species'].map(VegClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I follow you, but since you will have to create some sort of associative list, in the form

### plant | type

### oak | tree

### sawgrass | grass

### kkk | bush

### ...

Just create a hash table and get the type from the hash table.
You may read the table from an external file so it is not hardcoded in your program.